# Extracting String between given token

Tags: text-processing

I want to extract string between given token from a file, in my case it is between **%**. I have highlighted the strings in Bold below.

Content:

```
Update DIMENSIONPARAMETER set TEXTVALUE='http://%arm.se.host%:%arm.se.wls.listen.port%/CramerOSS/SyncEngineServlet/SyncProcessUnPauseServlet' where NAME='SyncEngine SyncProcessUnPauseServlet';
```

It also has input where simply %somestring% is present.
I want to extract that string only.

Comment: what distribution are you using? what is your `grep --version`?

Comment: I am using ubuntu.

Comment: and then grep version? also please [edit] into your question for the response, also better you add your `cut --version`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the lines in the file will be structured like the example, I believe you can use the command line program `cut` to treat the percent signs as field delimiters and pick the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> fields. So try running

```
cut -d "%" -f 2,4 --output-delimiter="," <file_name
```

Update:
I don't think anything needs to be changed for the other format because
in the pattern `%string%` the command above sees `string` as the second field and extracts it. I tried running

```
echo "%string%" | cut -d "%" -f 2,4 --output-delimiter=","
```

and `string` was printed to standard output.

Comment: I not only have input in above mentioned formats, iThere are other files in which i have %string% simply present. So, i basically want to cut that string between these 2 tokens.

Comment: I only want to extract that string between 2 tokens not the whole line in which it is present.

Comment: @karthik, its not taking --output-delimiter Getting this:cut: illegal option -- -
Usage: cut -b List [-n] [File...]
   or: cut -c List [File...]
   or: cut -f List [-d Character] [-s] [File...]

Comment: What happens when you run the command without the `-- output-delimiter` option? It looks like the `-- output-delimiter` option is available on Debian but not Ubuntu. The option means _separate fields with a comma in the output_. If Ubuntu's `cut` separates them some other way that's cool too.

Comment: Its working good for file where content is simply %string% but in those files where content is like **Update DIMENSIONPARAMETER set TEXTVALUE='http://%arm.se.host%:%arm.se.wls.listen.port%/CramerOSS/SyncEngineServlet/SyncProcessUnPauseServlet' where NAME='SyncEngine SyncProcessUnPauseServlet';.......** It is fetching the whole line.

Comment: Its working good with cat filename | grep "%" | cut -d "%" -f 2,4

Comment: Great! If using `grep` helped you then also try `cat filename | cut -d "%" -f 2,4 -s` because the `-s` should ignore all lines that don't contain the separator and do `grep`'s work.

Comment: Great its working fine too ! :)

Comment: @Karthik, what if i wanted to print all the strings that get extracted in new line(line by line) ?

Comment: Got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` as you mentioned you *`"have %string% simply present"`*:

```
grep -o '%[^%]*%' infile
```

Comment: Not working with flag -o, getting illegal input -o

Comment: @AbhijeetAnand if `grep -o` doesn't work, are you sure you are using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sed -r 's/[^%]*%([^%]*)%\S*(\s)*/\1\2/g'
```

Its easy to extract for single occurence using sed. For multiple occurences, I had found something like this before for similar problem. I couldn't find that thread.

**Okay, this detects first occurence correctly but not second occurence. Won't work.**

Karthik's answer works perfect!

Comment: I not only have input in above mentioned formats, iThere are other files in which i have %string% simply present. So, i basically want to cut that string between these 2 tokens

Comment: Any help highly appreciated